# ошибка при формирование большеразмерного массива в С++

Tags: c++

Объявление массивов:

```
float x[sum], y[sum],xp[sum],yp[sum];
```

где sum был вычислен заранее и получился равным где то 13000

Cпособ задания массивов.

```
for (j=1;j<n1;j++){
for (k=0;k<round(2*pi*j);k++){
        x[t]=j*h*cos(2*pi*k/(round(2*pi*j)));
        y[t]=j*h*sin(2*pi*k/(round(2*pi*j)));
        t++;
    };
```

t примерно равно 13000.
 По вышеуказанной схеме формируются 2 массива координат точек в одном слое double xp[j] и yp[j] длиной примерно g=13000 точек, необходимо создать одномерный массив (застакать n0+50=165 раз(количество слоев) массив координат), массив dz[g*(n0+50)] содержит координату слоя для точки у которой координата x берется из массива dx3, а у соотвественно из dy3:

```
for (int i=0;i<n0+50;i++){
 for (int j=0;j<g;j++){
    dx3[j+i*g]=xp[j];
    dy3[j+i*g]=yp[j];
    dz3[j+i*g]=h*i-Q;}}
```

либо можно создать двумерный массив, но это нежелательно:

```
for (int i=0;i<n0+50;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<g;j++){
         dxx[i][j]=xp[j];
        dyy[i][j]=yp[j];

    }
}
```

Из-за обоих циклов при запуске вылетает программа 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и просит JIT-отладку. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему или же покажите пример более оптимального кода.

Comment: JIT тут не при чем. Просто добавьте проверки индексов на выход за пределы допустимых значений и запустите программу под отладчиком. Если хотите получить более подробную помощь, то добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Например цикл будет не i<n0+50, а i<4, то у меня все равно ошибка, ошибки нет только при переприсвоении, так что дело не в выходе за пределы массива.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что Вы хотите на стеке создать 2 массива по 13000*165 элементов типа `double`? Т.е. каждый массив примерно по 17 Мб? А чему равен стек в Вашей системе? пару мегабайт? (ну, если линух, то может и до 8)... И если бы Вы приложили к вопросу способ задания Ваших массивов, то было бы гораздо проще понять Ваши проблемы.

Comment: Способ задания подразумевало и объявление массивов.

Comment: Проблему вызывают массивы dx3, dy3, dz3 размеры которых по 17 Мб. А не те, что Вы сейчас привели. Но полагаю, и этого достаточно, чтобы сделать вывод: Вы пытаетесь создать слишком большие массивы на стеке. Сделайте их динамическими, иначе ничего хорошего не получится. При попытке обратиться ко второму массиву Вы выходите за пределы стека программы и Вас бьют за это по рукам.

Comment: Ещё можно явно указать размер стэка, который выхотите, передав определённый флаг компилятору.
UPD. Точнее линкеру: `-Wl,--stack,268435456` - размер стэка 256 Mb

Comment: Разместите Ваши массивы вне функций в области видимости файла.

Answer (score 0):

Тут создаются слишком большие массивы:

```
 for (int i=0;i<n0+50;i++){
 for (int j=0;j<g;j++){
    dx3[j+i*g]=xp[j];
    dy3[j+i*g]=yp[j];
    dz3[j+i*g]=h*i-Q;}}
```

вместо массива используйте std::vector или создавайте массим в динамической памяти через new

Если вы добавить try catch блоки то наверняка увидете *cannot allocate memory*